# List array unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ObjectController script that looking for game objects and adding them to an array and another script that draws outline around those game objects. There're few tasks that I'm trying to achieve:

1. From ObjectController script List array I want to check what object is currently selected (clicked) so i won't be able to select (click) on other objects.
2. onMouseButtonDown(1) i want to clear selections (outline) from those objects.

Can you please guide me in the right direction?
I'm new to coding so please, go easy on me :D

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<SpriteOutline> objects;

    private void Start()
    {
        List<SpriteOutline> objectList = FindObjectsOfType<SpriteOutline>().ToList<SpriteOutline>();

        for (int i = 0; i < objectList.Count; i++)
        {
            objects.Add(objectList[i]);
        }
    }

    public List<SpriteOutline> GetList()
    {
        return objects;
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class SpriteOutline : MonoBehaviour {
    public Color OutlineColor = Color.white;
    private Color _currentColor = Color.clear;
    [Range(0, 16)]
    public int outlineSize = 1;

    private bool clicked = false;

    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    ObjectController objController;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        objController = GameObject.Find("ObjectController").GetComponent<ObjectController>();
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        for (int i = 0; i < objController.GetList().Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(i);
        }
    }

    void OnEnable() {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        UpdateOutline(true);
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        UpdateOutline(false);
    }

    void Update() {
        UpdateOutline(true);
        onMouseDown();
    }

    private void onMouseDown()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos;
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
        CapsuleCollider2D coll = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (coll.OverlapPoint(mousePos))
            {
                
                _currentColor = Color.clear;
                if (!clicked)
                {
                    _currentColor = OutlineColor;
                    clicked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    clicked = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            _currentColor = Color.clear;
        }
    }

    void UpdateOutline(bool outline) {
        MaterialPropertyBlock mpb = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
        spriteRenderer.GetPropertyBlock(mpb);
        mpb.SetFloat("_Outline", outline ? 1f : 0);
        mpb.SetColor("_OutlineColor", _currentColor);
        mpb.SetFloat("_OutlineSize", outlineSize);
        spriteRenderer.SetPropertyBlock(mpb);
    }
}
```

[image: Unity]

[image: Unity]

[hatebin](https://hatebin.com/wkjkglzsqq)

[hatebin](https://hatebin.com/bewpoakjem)

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();` and the for loop and write the one line  `return objController.GetList().GetEnumerator()` inside the method ?

Comment: @Soundararajan
Don't worry about IEnumerator, ill remove that line of code once i see its working... that is just for testing purposes :)

Comment: 1. when you call objController().GetList() is it returning a non-null value ? How do you guarantee that the object that you are storing the list is the same object that is returned when calling gameObject.Find("ObjectController") . What if it's a new instance .

Comment: @Soundararajan didn't think of that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit strange for me that you go through a controller class just to again find all instances of the actual class ;)

First you could simplify your code a lot:

```
public class ObjectController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The list is already public so no need to have a getter method ...
    public List<SpriteOutline> objects;

    private void Start()
    {
        // FindObjectsOfType returns an SpriteOutline[] 
        // so the easiest way of converting it to a list is
        objects = FindObjectsOfType<SpriteOutline>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you would later simply do

```
FindObjectOfType<ObjectController>().objects
```

---

However this isn't even necessary!

Instead of this manager/Singleton pattern here I would rather use a `static` and let your object instances register themselves and let your class handle it completely itself:

```
public class SpriteOutline : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] private Color OutlineColor = Color.white;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 16)] private int outlineSize = 1;

    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;

    // Here you actually register and unregisters instances
    private static readonly List<SpriteOutline> _instances = new List<SpriteOutline>();

    // If even needed public read-only access
    public ReadOnlyCollection<SpriteOutline> Instances => _instances.AsReadOnly();

    // The current selection
    private static readonly HashSet<SpriteOutline> _currentSelection = new HashSet<SpriteOutline>();

    // Again if needed a public read-only access
    public static HashSet<SpriteOutline> CurrentSelection => new HashSet<SpriteOutline>(_currentSelection);
     
    // backing field for storing the actual value of selected   
    private bool _isSelected;
       
    // Property which additionally updates the outline when changed
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            if(value == _isSelected) return;

            _isSelected = value;
            if(value)
            {
                _currentSelection.Add(this);
            }
            else
            {
                _currentSelection.Remove(this);
            }

            UpdateOutline(enabled, value);
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_spriteRenderer) _spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        // Register yourself
        _instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        UpdateOutline (true, _isSelected);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        UpdateOutline (false, _isSelected);
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        // Unregister yourself
        _instances.Remove(this);
        if(_currentSelection.Contains(this)) _currentSelection.Remove(this);
    }

    // This simplifies your query a lot since this is anyway only called
    // If the mouse is hovering the collider of this object
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // Toggle selection of this
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        { 
            IsSelected = !IsSelected;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Deselect this
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            IsSelected = false;
        }
    }

    void UpdateOutline(bool outline, bool selected) 
    {
        var mpb = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
        _spriteRenderer.GetPropertyBlock(mpb);
        mpb.SetFloat("_Outline", outline ? 1f : 0);
        mpb.SetColor("_OutlineColor", selected ? OutlineColor : Color.clear);
        mpb.SetFloat("_OutlineSize", outlineSize);
        spriteRenderer.SetPropertyBlock(mpb);
    }
}
```

---

If you rather want to select only exactly one object at a time then I would exchange the `HashSet<SpriteOutline> _currentSelection` by something like

```
    // The current selection
    private static SpriteOutline _currentSelection;

    // Again if needed a public read-only access
    public static SpriteOutline CurrentSelection => _currentSelection;
```

accordingly change

```
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            if(value == _isSelected) return;

            // assuming that if you set this via property it should
            // overwrite the current selection
            // otherwise you would here do
            //if(_currentSelection && _currentSelection != this) return;

            if(_currentSelection && _currentSelection != this) _currentSelection.IsSelected = false;

            _isSelected = value;
           
            _currentSelection = value ? this : null;
           
            UpdateOutline(enabled, value);
        }
    }
```

and finally you wanted to block the input on objects that are not the selection:

```
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // Toggle selection of this
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        { 
            if(_currentSelection && _currentSelection != this) return;

            IsSelected = !IsSelected;
        }
    }
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me, maybe i'm doing something wrong..